# If Statement in HTML can't exit

Tags: c#, html, if-statement, sidebar, menubar

I'm making a sidebar/menubar for a website. The first problem I was having, was that it was showing up on the login page so you didn't have to login to get to the page. I added an if statement to it (see below) but now it only shows up on the home page ONLY. I need it show up everywhere else too. It goes to the if statement but when I click on another page it goes back, and that statement comes up false even though I'm already logged in

```
@if (Model.session != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.session.getUsername()))
{

  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
    <a href="~/home/consoliplexMain">Home</a>
    <a href="~/home/employeeLinksFullPage">Consoliplex Family</a>
    <a href="~/home/humanResources">Human Resources</a>
    <a href="~/home/companyLinks">Company Resources</a>
    <a href="~/home/OurStory">Our Story</a>
    <a href="~/home/ourCustomers">Our Customers</a>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Menu </button>
  </div>

  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
    }
  </script>

} @if (Model.session != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.session.getUsername()))
  {


  }
```